# How to download webpage as pdf in nodejs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, ejs

I have tried to download a webpage to pdf format in nodejs via button in a page.
once the user will click on the button the webpage should be saved as .pdf file.

Thanks,
Dia

Comment: I see no evidence that you tried to download a webpage as pdf. Please [edit] your question to include the minimal code to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with phantom.js

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

You can call phantom from node as an external process, if you really need to.